# How to accsses a struct member of a struct that was setted as a pointer?

Tags: c, struct

I am trying to create a submarine game in c so i made a sturct that will connect the "location" of the submarine on the Board to the submarine it self, these are the structs i use;

```
struct Point_s
{
    int x;
    int y;
};

struct BoardPart_s
{
    boolean ishit;//yes = 1 no = 0
    Submarine* Sub;
};

   struct Submarine_s
{
    Point start;
    Point end;
    int Life;// this is calculated from the diffrence of the non equal part of the x/y Point
};
```

now when the assigment was stated like this

```
Board[xstart][yend]->Sub=&(Plist->sub);// plist is a linked list conatining a submarine
```

however when i try to accses its member life like that

```
   BoardPart BoardP2[BoardSize][BoardSize];// boardsize is 10
.
.
.
.
.
if( BoardP2[x][y]->Sub->Life <= 0)
```

i get a compiler error "request for member 'Life' in something not a structure or union"

i should note that the typedef that are in the header are stated like this

```
typedef struct Point_s* Point;
typedef struct Submarine_s* Submarine;
typedef struct Command_s* Command;
typedef struct BoardPart_s* BoardPart;
```

Comment: Did you properly `typedef struct Submarine_s Submarine;` somewhere before you use that type?

Comment: Put the full code. You are accessing to `Submarine`'s `Life`but in your code it is a `Submarine_s`which has a `Life`attribute

Comment: yes i used an ADT defintion on the header

Comment: @OmerGuttman `typedef struct Submarine_s* Submarine;` <- this is one level of pointer too much, since in `struct Boardpart_s` you define a pointer to `Submarine`, too. You probably want to remove the asterisk there and also remove the & in the assignment

Comment: I'd rename `ishit` to `is_hit`... just saying ;)

Comment: What is `BoardP2`?  Please read this: [mcve]. BTW typedefing to hide pointer types such as `typedef struct BoardPart_s* BoardPart` is a very bad idea, because when you write `BoardPart a;` you don't know immediately that `a` is a pointer, where as if you write `struct BoardPart_s *a;` you do.

Comment: You're trying to access the Life member of a Submarine_s pointer. Either don't typdef submarine_s as a pointer or don't declare sub as a submarine pointer.

Comment: so is there a way i could link servral boardparts into the same submarine without using it as a pointer?

Comment: Did you try `BoardP2[x][y]->Sub.Life` ? We don't know what is `BoardP2` ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example the `Sub` field of `BoardPart_s` struct is `Submarine *`, and `Submarine` is `Submarine_s *`. So to access the `Life` field of that `Sub` you should write `(**(BoardP2[x][y]->Sub)).Life`.

To avoid this kind of confusion you should always avoid typedefing to pointers to types.